# write data to excel in java first tab data is not displaying while writing second tab

Tags: java, excel

When I add data to second tab in excel sheet. First tab data is not displaying.
If i remove code for second tab, first tab data is visible.

```
HSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("A ");
HSSFSheet sheet2 = wb.createSheet("B");

HSSFFont headerFont = wb.createFont();
headerFont.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);

headerStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
headerStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.PALE_BLUE.index);
headerStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
headerStyle.setFont(headerFont);
try
{
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Report.xls");

        HSSFRow sessionname = sheet1.createRow(0);
        HSSFCell title = sessionname.createCell(0);
        title.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
        title.setCellValue("Supported cipher Report");

        HSSFRow row = sheet1.createRow(5);

        HSSFCell cell0 = row.createCell(0);
        cell0.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
        cell0.setCellValue("One"); 

        HSSFCell cell1 = row.createCell(1);
        cell1.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
        cell1.setCellValue("two");

        HSSFCell cell2 = row.createCell(2);
        cell2.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
        cell2.setCellValue("three");

        HSSFCell cell3 = row.createCell(3);
        cell3.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
        cell3.setCellValue("four");

        HSSFCell cell4 = row.createCell(4);
        cell4.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
        cell4.setCellValue("five");


        if (!list.isEmpty())
        {
            int rowNumber = 6;
            for (Result s : supportedlist)
            {
                HSSFRow nextrow = sheet1.createRow(rowNumber);
                nextrow.createCell(0).setCellValue(s.One());
                nextrow.createCell(1).setCellValue(s.Two());
                nextrow.createCell(2).setCellValue(s.Three());
                nextrow.createCell(3).setCellValue(s.four());
                nextrow.createCell(4).setCellValue(s.five());
                rowNumber++;
            }
        }
        sheet1.autoSizeColumn(0);
        sheet1.autoSizeColumn(1);
        sheet1.autoSizeColumn(2);
        sheet1.autoSizeColumn(3);
        sheet1.autoSizeColumn(4);
        System.out.println("sheet1 writting");

    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.flush();
    fileOut.close();
```

when i pass sheet2 and remaining code is same as above.
sheet1 tab data is not displayed while sheet2 data is desplayed.

Comment: I don't see you write to `sheet2`. Any chance you accidentially write to the wrong tab or overwrite the first? Did you debug your code?

Comment: i also debug the code. I checked values during debugging. If i see output before passing sheet2. data is there. once sheet2 is passed, data is vanished. Please sugguest. Is there any problem with FileOutputStream? If i use FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Report.xls", true);  --> all the times shee1 data is displayed. sheet2 data is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing is you are changing the values of `sheet1` to `sheet2` after writing to `sheet1`. Now, what happens according to your code is you are again creating/writing to a file. So, it `replaces` the old file and data and writes to a new file in second sheet.

Below line overwrites the data when you run the program second time

```
 FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Report.xls");
```

What you should do is when writing to `sheet2` you should **check** if file exists or not. If exists then it adds new sheet to existing excel file. If not exists create a new file and then create a sheet.

Do something like this

```
   FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

    if (file.exists()) {
        try {
            workbook = (HSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(file);
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet2");
    }
    else{
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet1");
    }
    workbook.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
```

To avoid overwriting to a existing file use below. This will append the data to the existing file.

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Report.xls", true);
```

Comment: This is what I suspect as well but without any additional information it's hard to tell. Besides that, I'd not append to an xlsx file (your last line) since this most probably will write another header to the file or otherwise mess up the file format.

Answer (score 0):

problem was I created two instances[new createExcel(one); and new createExcel(two); while invoking the function. since wb is part of instance. so it created new excel with sheet1 and sheet2  inside. and since this time I write sheet2 data only. so sheet2 data was only displaying. Thanks for the support.